# Automating the Connection to Big Query Without a Service Account

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to be able to run BigQuery queries in Python without a service account (I don't have access to it right now and it's going to take some time before I am granted this).

At the moment, I am able to do this by generating the Google Client ID and secret this way:

1. Going to https://console.cloud.google.com/
2. Choosing the Project that I have access to: my_project
3. Activating the Cloud Shell

   a) In the shell, type in "gcloud auth application-default login"

   b) Answer y in the prompt message

   c) Click on the link provided

   d) Signing in with my Google Account

   e) So that the Google Auth Library can access my Google Account

   f) Then a verification code would be generated. It would look something like
   "**4/4A_something_something**"

   g) This creates a temporary credentials file with my Client ID and Secret. It would be something like "**/tmp/tmp.some_strings/application_default_credentials.json**"

   h) Then I run "cat /tmp/tmp.some_strings/application_default_credentials.json" in order to view the contents of the .json file. It would look like this:
   {
   **"client_id": whatever_code,
   "client_secret": whatever_code,
   "refresh_token": whatever_code,
   "type":"authorized_user"**
   }

   i) Then I save the outputs of that dictionary to a .json file in my directory
4. on command prompt, I run "**set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=path_of_the_json_file**"

Once I have all of this setup, then I can run queries in Jupyter notebook with the bigquery module. However, every time I lose access to the VDI or need to login again, I have to reset the token in order to regain access. Is there a way to automate all of the steps above? Or is it only possible through a service account?

Comment: A Service Account is the appropriate way to authenticate code to Cloud Platform. What is the reason for your reticence? The approach you're following is creating a synthetic Service Account using your user credentials but this is not recommended. The account that results has extensive (equivalent to your user account's permissions) and is implemented in a way that can cause problems with some Google services.

Comment: It's not that I don't want the service account option. I know it's the best option! It's just that it's not a viable option for me at the moment. It's something that I have requested but not available. So I have to find a workaround.

Comment: Your only other option to authenticate is to use Oauth. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/end-user-installed